# AS3: How to know if a textField is Dynamic

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

Is it possible to know if a textField inside of a Display Object is dynamic?
I'm looping all the children of a Display Object, and I would like to find only Dynamic text fields (I've input tf too, and I want to avoid them)
THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type property, which will return a string TextFieldType enum value:

```
//Assuming a DisplayObjectContainer called 'doc':
for (var i:int = 0; i < doc.numChildren; i++) 
{
    var tf:TextField = doc.getChildAt(i) as TextField;
    if (tf != null) // Will be null if the child isn't a TextField
    {
        switch(tf.type)
        {
            case TextFieldType.DYNAMIC:
                trace("Dynamic");
                break;
            case TextFieldType.INPUT:
                trace("Input");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation is nice and clear:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#type

Comment: thx, shame on me, I missed the type property of the documentation :(